# How to detect time when shared posix ipc memory was changed in python3

Tags: python, posix, ipc, semaphore

I have two processes that access shared memory, process A writes to it and process B reads it.  I am using python3 and the posix_ipc package.

Process B occasionally needs to make a decision based on the state of the data in the shared memory but it has to do an intensive transformation on the data to do this.  I only want to do that transformation if I am certain that process A has changed the data since process B last transformed it.

Is there a way to get a last changed timestamp or trigger an event when the shared memory changes or do I need to set up some other mechanism for process A to notify process B when its changed the data?

Comment: Yes you need another mechanism. But as you did not describe much precisely the way A and B can/must access data, we can't say much.

Comment: thanks, I ended up adding a field to the shared memory that was the last write time and that seems to serve me needs.